# how to use ds-digital in iOS 3.1?

Tags: iphone, fonts, custom-font

I have iPhone 4g with iOS 4.1 and I have one 3g with iOS 3.1.3. I have added custom ds-digital.ttf fonts to .plist file. I have used it as below in program

```
    [hourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ds-digital" size:120.0]];
```

While "Build and Run" of 4g, there is no issue, it works well, but while on 3g, it is giving SIGABRT as below

```
     Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: font != nil'
    2011-08-25 14:38:17.972 FinalAlarmClock[702:207] Stack: (
```

I googled it and found that iOS which are less than 3.2 don't support the **"Custom Fonts"** , I downloaded an app from appStore, name is Alarm Clock by iHandySoft Inc, and as it is running with my 3.1.3 iOS very fine,

I am unable to understand that what is it using, I saw the font **"DBLCDTempBlack"**, but it is not used, both are different, 
What should I do, I want to user ds-digital, because iOS 3.1.3 havn't such fonts in their Family.

Help!